# R script ggplot: Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a paneled plot in R showing individual data and the means for each panel.  This original plot works, but when I try to change the color of the individual data based on another variable the code breaks, and I get the error message: Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero.

I have pasted 1) sample data, 2) the original code that works and 3) the code with the color variable that does not work.

I would really appreciate any help you can offer to fix this.

Thank you!
Natalie

```
    library(ggplot2)

    sample <- structure(list(id = c(2108L, 2123L, 2718L, 2760L, 2133L, 2162L,   2216L, 2234L, 2298L, 2108L, 2123L, 2718L, 2760L, 2133L, 2162L, 2216L, 2234L, 2298L), Timeline_Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Baseline", "Post"), class = "factor"), Treatment_Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Health Ed", "MBSR"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Baseline/Health Ed", "Baseline/MBSR", "Post/Health Ed", "Post/MBSR"), class = "factor"), Y_mb = c(1.58, 1.66, 2.27, 1.87, 1.75, 1.65, 1.82, 1.12, 2.05, 2.29, 2.11, 1.55, 1.72, 2.28, 1.71, 1.69, 1.98, 2.28), slope = c(0.71, 0.45, -0.72, -0.15, 0.53, 0.06, -0.13, 0.86, 0.23, 0.71, 0.45, -0.72, -0.15, 0.53, 0.06, -0.13, 0.86, 0.23), slope_group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "Timeline_Code", "Treatment_Code", "Group", "Y_mb", "slope", "slope_group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

this works

```
    p <- ggplot(data = sample, aes(x = Timeline_Code, y = Y_mb, group = id)) + geom_line(col = "dark grey") + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Baseline","Post")) + facet_grid(. ~Treatment_Code) + stat_summary(aes(group = 1)) + stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", size = 3, col = "black", se = FALSE)+ labs(x="", y = "Y_mb") + theme_classic()

    p
```

now I want to keep the structure of the above graph, but change the color of the individual lines depending on whether the slope is positive or negative. I added col = slope_group to ggplot.  Part of the code works and plots the graph, but does not produce the means. Seems to be a problem with stat_summary because everything works until that point.

```
    p <- ggplot(data = sample, aes(x = Timeline_Code, y = Y_mb, group = id, col = slope_group)) + geom_line() + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Baseline","Post")) + facet_grid(. ~Treatment_Code) + stat_summary(aes(group = 1)) + stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", size = 3, col = "black", se = FALSE)+ labs(x="", y = "Y_mb") + theme_classic() 

    p
```

error message

```
Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero
```

session info

```
# sessionInfo()
#   R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
#   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

#locale:
#[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

#other attached packages:
#[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1

#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       grid_2.15.2       
# [5] gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-22        munsell_0.4       
# [9] plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2    
# [13] scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your R and ggplot2 are outdated. I see no error on R 3.2.1 and ggplot2 2.0.0.

Comment: Fantastic!  updated R and ggplot2 and it works now.  Thank you!

Comment: Questions without answers will eventually be deleted. I would suggest answering it and marking it correct.

Comment: For anyone arriving here because a ggplot won't convert nicely to `ggplotly()`, it's because `ggplotly()` doesn't like certain layers. In my case, when i removed `xlab(element_blank()) + ylab(element_blank()) +` it worked perfectly